# When we use Reference type and Object Type

Tags: java

I am having a doubt regarding ArrayList and List.
In which case we should use ArraryList like:

```
ArrayList obj = new ArrayList();
```

And in which case we should use List Interface.

```
List obj =  new ArrayList();
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Search on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=) will provide more info on code than googling around

Comment: Off topic note: you should always include the type for a List or ArrayList, i.e. `ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<>();` or List<Object> obj = new List<>();`

Comment: In case if dont wanna make my list Generic then???

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call a method that is specific to an implementation, use the implementation.

When you write :

```
List obj =  new ... //ArrayList() or LinkedList()
```

the compiler only knows that obj is a `List`. Hence, you cannot use methods that are specific to one implementation.

For example, if you need to access the last element of a `LinkedList`, you need to declare it like this :

```
LinkedList = obj = new LinkedList();
```

Now, `obj` is a `LinkedList`. Hence, you can use `obj.last()`.

Comment: can you please tell me the same example in ArrayList scenario. 
when i write ArrayList obj = new ArrayList(); and List lst =  new ArrayList();

In both cases i can get the same method. then what is the diff ?

Comment: @ArvindVishwakarma I don't know any method that is specific to the ArrayList. This implementation is only a list stored in an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use methods specific to ArrayList you want to first case, otherwise it's better to use the second case. With the second case you don't have to change as much if you want to switch to a different List implementation.

Comment: Don't mind!!! Give some more info on this :(